# tab inside fragmentactivity with pager

Tags: android

I am using FragmentActivity to create tabs 
when i run the app i get the following error

```
info cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

on this line

```
List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Info.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Search.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Home.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Profile.class.getName()));
this.mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
```

in the intialiseViewPager function

check this pastie.org/8090463

Any ideas pls

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

#### According to your error : info cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment

I think Your `FragmentActivity` extends `android.app.Fragment`.
 
just `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment` then the cast will be worked.

Edited:-

Just extend `Fragment` instead of `FragmentActivity` 
 [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#)